# ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hbase, bigdata, apache-zookeeper

I have a standalone VM Ubuntu setup, on which i have installed Hadoop and Hbase,
But i am struggling with following error for long time.

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times
```

I am getting error while doing create table in hbase shell `create 't1','f1','f2'`

**For fixing this error i tired following things:**

1. Change `127.0.1.1` to `127.0.0.1` for host in file `/etc/hosts`.
2. appended `ubuntu`  to `127.0.0.1` host line in file `/etc/hosts`.
3. Tried to run hbase by using `hbase-daemon.sh <start/stop> <service_name>` command.

But nothing of above seems to work.

I am using Hadoop Version 1.1.2 and Hbase Version 0.94.8.

can someone please provide some help on this i am stuck on this for long time.

Comment: Can you check whether a java process named Hmaster is running on your VM ,and also can you post the log in the base log directory.

Comment: when i type command `jps` then i see process `Hmaster` process running along with other processes, and which logs i should refer for debugging this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem after installing `Hbase` & did the below steps.

Just in your terminal go to `Hbase->bin & run start-hbase.sh` shown below .

```
user@client:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ start-hbase.sh
```

Then type `jps` in your terminal .Now `HMaster` will active .

```
user@client:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ jps

4492 SecondaryNameNode

11784 Jps

4792 TaskTracker

4275 DataNode

4583 JobTracker

4057 NameNode

11467 Main

8297 HMaster
```

After this I could create a table .

Comment: I don't know why this answer doesn't have at least 100 points. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

actually there is bug in hbase version hbase-0.94.8,inside hbase-site.xml if u write roodir instead of rootdir it will work.actually we have to write hbase.rootdir

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.roodir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
```